# Are these abrasions problematic in a carbon fork dropout?

Tags: carbon, carbon-fork

Got my first road bike with a carbon fork and when installing the front wheel the skewer slipped a little. Now I got some shiny surface lines there on the carbon surface. I wouldn't even call it scratches or abrasions as it's only visible with reflecting light. Is this already a problem with carbon or am I good to go?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]

Edit: In addition two more pictures made in daylight of outer dropout part. On one side there seems to be some small damage but I can't imagine the happened from the slipping skewer as it was almost lose already. Just want to make sure if this looks ok. If one can even say this over pictures...

[image: 7]
[image: 8]

Comment: Curious that its a QR on a new bike - Is it a rim brake ?   I can't see any mounts.

Comment: It's actually a DT Swiss RWS. Just wrote QR for easier explanation. It has rim brakes.

Answer (score 9):

This is a common concern. It is inevitable that exposed carbon wear surfaces are going to get scratched.

I think you'll find a range of opinions on this. My own is that this is a problem and it is irresponsible of bike makers to sell frames like this. Some do (or did) have metal faceplates on the wear surfaces, which I think is the right thing to do. There are carbon repair shops that will add them on. I did a little checking just now and was surprised that I could not find aftermarket dropout faceplates sold retail.

Comment: I have to agree. We know that carbon doesn't stand up well to scratching or impacts. This was not a good design choice. It could be that the manufacturer reinforced the area somehow, so that it can better stand up to clamping by a knurled skewer nut, but who knows.

Comment: Corroborating statement by carbon fiber repairer https://youtu.be/TPcm7-KvytI?t=459

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added two more images in daylight. On one dropout I can see a small nick but I think this didn't result from the slipping skewer as it was almost lose already. Would really appreciate if you could take another look though.

Comment: It's not a problem *now* but it's going to get worse with time, and carbon fiber shreds in a way that other materials don't. It makes me wonder if anyone's tried applying an ablative coating and reapplying it periodically.

Comment: @AdamRice A couple of thin steel washers is likely a better solution.

Answer (score 8):

I'll tend to think the opposite to @Adam, with today's liability and consumer protection laws, if these scratches, which a normal wear and tear, are a problem, the manufacturer has a huge liability on its hands. Ther reputational risk probably exceeds the no unsubstantial financial risk.

Obviously, this depends on the frame manufacturer. If it is a frame from a big name, common brand, I would say you have no problem to worry about. If it is a direct import from a cheap Chinese clone maker, I would be less happy to assert its not a problem.

Comment: I added two more images in daylight. Would be really glad if someone could take another look. I can see a small nick but can't imagine it's from the slipping skewer.

Comment: @conste Your pictures were fine already. It doesn't change the answer: The drop outs should have been made out of metal, but the manufacturer obviously thought it was ok. You don't have anyting but normal wear and tear.